# Check Gitlab CE API version - Docker Kubernetes build

Tags: docker, gitlab

I need to check what version to the api my Gitlab is using. I found some docker files with "apiVersion". But I am not entirely sure if that pertains to Gitlab api or something else.

I am using this build: https://github.com/IBM/Kubernetes-container-service-GitLab-sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from the [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/v3_to_v4.html):

> Since GitLab 9.0, API V4 is the preferred version to be used.
>
> API V3 will be unsupported from GitLab 9.5, to be released on August 22, 2017. It will be removed in GitLab 9.5 or later. In the meantime, we advise you to make any necessary changes to applications that use V3. The V3 API documentation is still available.